# How to use recursion to simplify repeated code?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a triangle/ tree? of any size M.

In this case size M is 3:

```
  1
 2 3
4 5 6
```

my goal is to output all the combinations as if you were traversing from top to bottom. The results would be {124}{125}{135}{136}

How can I combine my for loops with recursion to simplify it

```
private ArrayList<int[]> listOfCombinations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
public void callSequence(int[] combo, int size, int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4 && size >= 3; i++) {
        // System.out.println("combinations array :" + combo[0] + combo[1] + combo[2]);
        listOfCombinations.add(combo);
        listOfCombinations.get(i)[0] = 1;
        System.out.print(listOfCombinations.get(i)[0]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        listOfCombinations.add(combo);
        listOfCombinations.get(i)[1] = 2;
        System.out.print(listOfCombinations.get(i)[1]);
    }
    for (int i=2; i < 4; i++) {
        listOfCombinations.add(combo);
        listOfCombinations.get(i)[1] = 3;
        System.out.print(listOfCombinations.get(i)[1]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=4; i<=5; i++) {
        listOfCombinations.get(i)[2] = i;
        System.out.print(listOfCombinations.get(i)[2]);
    }
    for (int i=5; i<=6; i++) {
        listOfCombinations.get(i)[2] = i;
        System.out.print(listOfCombinations.get(i)[2]);
    }
```

When I call this function it prints

```
 1 1 1 1
 2 2 3 3 
 4 5 5 6
```

so the arrays are {1,2,4}{1,2,5}{1,3,5}{1,3,6} which is the right output but this is a bad way of doing it. I'm trying to think of how to do this with recursion instead so I can simplify it.

Comment: I'm curious, is your data for the pyramid always going to be in numeric order of 1, 2, 3, ect. from left to right?

Comment: yes it's of primary key's that are mapped to other more complicated data. the data is related in sets {2,3}{4,5,6} etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data will behave like this:

```
RowNum:           Position:
  0                   1
  1                  2 3
  2                 4 5 6
```

Then you can take advantage of the fact a left Position is equal to the Position above it plus the RowNum, and a right Position is equal to the Position above it plus the RowNum plus 1. So, you can build a recursive algorithm using that fact like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int maxRows = 3;
  paths(maxRows, 1, 1, "1");
}

/**
 * Recursive top to bottom depth first approach
 * 
 * @param maxRow Total number of rows to travel down.
 * @param rowNum The current row an iteration is on.
 * @param position The position number above the current iteration.
 * @param values The values so far along the path.
 */
public static void paths(int maxRow, int rowNum, int position, String values) {
  //You've hit the bottom so print the results
  if(rowNum >= maxRow) {
    System.out.println(values);
    return;
  }

  int nextRow = rowNum + 1;

  //Calculate position for left side branch, append it to values, and start next iteration
  int leftPosition = position + rowNum;
  String leftValues = values + " " + leftPosition;
  paths(maxRow, nextRow, leftPosition, leftValues);

  //Calculate position for right side branch, append it to values, and start next iteration
  int rightPosition = position + rowNum + 1;
  String rightValues = values + " " + rightPosition;
  paths(maxRow, nextRow, rightPosition, rightValues);
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's a version that stores everything in containers and has an overloaded version to simplify the parameters it actually needs from a user.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initializes the path function
    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = paths(4);
    System.out.println(allPaths);
  }

  /**
   * Recursively find all paths in a pyramid like node path. Depth first search.
   * <pre><code>
   * Row   Position     
   *  0        1       
   *  1       2 3     
   *  2      4 5 6    
   *  3     7 8 9 10 
   *  </code></pre>
   *  
   * @param maxDepth Total number of rows to travel down.
   * @return Collection of all the paths in their own collections.
   */
  public static List<List<Integer>> paths(int maxDepth) {
    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
    path.add(1);
    paths(maxDepth, 1, 1, path, allPaths);
    return allPaths;
  }

  /**
   * Recursively find all paths in a pyramid like node path. Depth first search.
   *   
   * @param maxDepth Total number of rows to travel down.
   * @param currentDepth The current depth an iteration is on.
   * @param topPosition The position number above the current iteration.
   * @param currentPath The values so far along the path.
   * @param allPaths Container for all the paths when it reaches the end.
   */
  private static void paths(int maxDepth, int currentDepth, int topPosition, List<Integer> currentPath, List<List<Integer>> allPaths) {
    //You've hit the bottom so print the results
    if(currentDepth >= maxDepth) {
      allPaths.add(currentPath);
      return;
    }

    int nextDepth = currentDepth + 1;

    //Calculate position for left side branch, append it to values, and start it's branching iterations
    int leftPosition = topPosition + currentDepth;
    List<Integer> leftArray = new ArrayList<>(currentPath);
    leftArray.add(leftPosition);
    paths(maxDepth, nextDepth, leftPosition, leftArray, allPaths);

   //Calculate position for right side branch, append it to values, and start it's branching iterations
    int rightPosition = topPosition + currentDepth + 1;
    List<Integer> rightArray = new ArrayList<>(currentPath);
    rightArray.add(rightPosition);
    paths(maxDepth, nextDepth, rightPosition, rightArray, allPaths);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is that the two children of the node `n` in row `r` are just `n + r` and `n + r + 1`.  With that said, you can build a fairly simple recursion.  (Sorry, you'll have to do your own conversion to Java!)

```js
const paths = (levels, node = 1, row = 1, res = [[1]]) => levels < 2
  ? res
  : [
      ... paths (levels - 1, node + row, row + 1, res .map ((path) => [...path, node + row])),
      ... paths (levels - 1, node + row + 1, row + 1, res .map ((path) => [...path, node + row + 1]))
    ]


const results = paths (4)

console.log (
  results.map (JSON.stringify) .join ('\n')
)
```

There will be `2 ^ n` results, so I wouldn't want to try 50 levels deep!

---

### Update

This is a perhaps cleaner way of writing that recursion:

```js
const last = (xs) => xs[xs.length - 1];

const paths = (levels, row = 1, res = [[1]]) => levels < 2
  ? res
  : paths (
      levels - 1, 
      row + 1, 
      res.flatMap(xs => [[...xs, last(xs) + row], [...xs, last(xs) + row + 1]])
    )


const results = paths (4)

console.log (
  results.map (JSON.stringify) .join ('\n')
)
```

It's the same algorithm, just a cleaner way to write the recursion.  We accept the number of levels deep, then default the row number (`1`) and results (`[[1]]`) for the first level.  The recurrence subtracts one from the level, adds one to the row, and then calculates the next row's result by, creating two entries for each entry in the row, one which appends the last value plus the row number, and one which appends one more than the last value plus the row number.  This feels cleaner than the first approach.

Comment: "There will be 2 ^ n results" Shouldn't there be 2 ^ (totalNumberRows - 1) results?

Comment: Yes, or "where `n` is the number of rows."

Comment: Just clarifying, since you were using `n` to represent the node value earlier in your example.